# Extract public key from Google "oauth2/v1/certs" cert in PEM format using Go

Tags: go, rsa, google-oauth, urlfetch, openid-connect

I fetched the Google cert from:

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

but I don't know how to parse the cert in Go and extract the public key and make it aplicable for use in rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15() to verify id token (openID connect) signature. If someone could advise me I would appreciate it. Here is the code what I already have:

```
res, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return 
}

certs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
res.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return 
}
//extract kid from token header
var header interface{}
log.Printf("Oauth header: %v", headerOauth)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(headerOauth), &header)

token_kid := header.(map[string]interface{})["kid"]
//get modulus and exponent from the cert

var goCertificate interface{}

err = json.Unmarshal(certs, &goCertificate)    

k := goCertificate.(map[string]interface{})[token_kid.(string)]

google_cert := k.(string)
block_pub, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(google_cert))
certInterface, err := x509.ParseCertificates(block_pub.Bytes)
log.Printf("certInterface: %v", *certInterface.PublicKey)
//I know the line below is wrong but thats how I usualy parse public keys
pubkeyInterface, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(certInterface.Bytes)
pKey, ok := pubkeyInterface.(*rsa.PublicKey)
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be way off here (not familiar with x509/rsa) but `ParseCertificates` returns all the keys:

```
func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    var header = map[string]string{
        "kid": "ef9007a67db85f13ed67462abe2df63145c09aaf",
    }

    token_kid := header["kid"]

    defer res.Body.Close()
    var certs map[string]string
    dec := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    dec.Decode(&certs)
    // add error checking
    google_cert := certs[token_kid]
    block_pub, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(google_cert))
    certInterface, err := x509.ParseCertificates(block_pub.Bytes)
    log.Printf("certInterface: %#v", certInterface)
    pkey := certInterface[0].PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)
    log.Printf("pkey: %v", pkey)
}
```

Comment: thank You, but when I run the script with my id token it returns the following error: certInterface: []*x509.Certificate{(*x509.Certificate)(0xc210165480)}
Error verifying key crypto/rsa: verification error#

Comment: @kingSlayer that should probably be a different question, I'm not familiar enough with crypto/rsa though.